# Is there a quick way to format an XmlDocument for display in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I want to output my InnerXml property for display in a web page. I would like to see indentation of the various tags. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: As times goes by and we have LINQ to XML now, you can use `XDocument` class from `System.Xml.Linq` namespace to print out your XML with indentation: `XDocument.Parse(doc.InnerXml)`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's a little class that I put together some time ago to do exactly this.

It assumes that you're working with the XML in string format.

```
public static class FormatXML
{
    public static string FormatXMLString(string sUnformattedXML)
    {
        XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
        xd.LoadXml(sUnformattedXML);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
        XmlTextWriter xtw = null;
        try
        {
            xtw = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
            xtw.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
            xd.WriteTo(xtw);
        }
        finally
        {
            if(xtw!=null)
                xtw.Close();
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's even easier when you add it as an extension method :)

Comment: This didn't work for me :(  `sb.ToString()` had a \r\n after <?xml version ="1.0" ?> but the rest of the string is still all on one line, no indenting at all.

Comment: XmlTextWriter implements IDisposable so cleaner to use `using` instead of try-finally.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with code formatters. You would have to html encode the xml into the page first.

Google has [a nice prettifyer](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) that is capable of visualizing XML as well as several programming languages.

Basically, put your XML into a pre tag like this:

```
<pre class="prettyprint"> 
    &lt;link href="prettify.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /&gt;
    &lt;script type="text/javascript" src="prettify.js">&lt;/script&gt;
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [XML Web Server Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0dfkwww1(VS.80,loband).aspx) to display the content of an xml document on a web page.

EDIT: You should pass the entire XmlDocument to the Document property of the XML Web Server Control to display it. You don't need to use the InnerXml property.

Answer (score 0):

If identation is your only cocern and if you can afford to launch xternall process, you can process xml file with [HTML Tidy](http://www.w3.org/People/Raggett/tidy/) console tool (~100K).

The code is:

```
tidy --input-xml y --output-xhtml y --indent "1" $(FilePath)
```

Then you can display idented string on web page once you get rid of special chars.

It would be also easy to create recursive function that makes such output - simply iterate nodes starting from the root and enter next recursion step for child node, passing identation as a parameter to each new recursion call.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the free [Actipro CodeHighlighter](http://www.actiprosoftware.com/Products/DotNet/ASPNET/CodeHighlighter/Default.aspx) for ASP.NET - it can neatly display XML and other formats.

Or are you more interested in actually formatting your XML? Then have a look at the XmlTextWriter - you can specify things like Format (indenting or not) and the indent level, and then write out your XML to e.g. a MemoryStream and read it back from there into a string for display.

Marc

Answer (score 0):

Use an XmlTextWriter with the XmlWriterSettings set up so that indentation is enabled. You can use a StringWriter as "temporary storage" if you want to write the resulting string onto screen.